# adding html span between date and time in php

Tags: php, html, date, time

I am working on a php code as shown below in which I want to add a span in between date and time in php.

```
<time style="width:194px;" datetime="<?php echo esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'H:i d-m-Y')) ?>"
    data-timezone="<?php echo esc_attr($tz_param) ?>"><?php echo esc_html(date_format($ts, 'F j H:i')) ?></time>
```

The above php code prints the following:

`September 4 05:09`

On inspect, it shows like that:

```
<time style="width:194px;" datetime="05:09 04-09-2019" data-timezone="et">September 4 05:09</time>
```

**Problem Statement:**

What I want to achieve now is, I want to place the time in **span**. This is what I have tried. I am wondering if its the correct way to place the **time in span** in php.

```
<time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr(date_format($ts, 'H:i d-m-Y')) ?>"
    data-timezone="<?php echo esc_attr($tz_param) ?>"><?php echo esc_html(date_format($ts, 'F j').'<span>'.(date_format($ts, 'H:i'))).'</span>' ?></time>
```

**On inspect, it should be like this**:

```
<time style="width:194px;" datetime="05:09 04-09-2019" data-timezone="et">September 4<span>05:09</span></time>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making it more difficult than needs be.  You can simply `escape` the characters in `span` to make it accessible without concatenation.  IE:

```
<?php

$ts=time();

echo date('F j &\nb\sp;  &\nb\sp; <\s\p\a\n>H:i<\/\s\p\a\n>', $ts);

?>
```

Would output

```
September 4 &nbsp;  &nbsp; <span>15:56</span>
```

**UPDATE**

```
$ts=time();

echo '<time style="width:194px;" datetime="' . date('H:i m-d-Y', $ts) . '" data-timezone="et">' . date('F j &\nb\sp;  &\nb\sp; <\s\p\a\n>H:i<\/\s\p\a\n>', $ts) . '</time>';
```

Will echo

```
<time style="width:194px;" datetime="16:12 09-04-2019" data-timezone="et">September 4 &nbsp;  &nbsp; <span>16:12</span></time>
```

This was tested and works HOWEVER I don't have the function `esc_attr($tz_param)` so you will have to manually put that in the string yourself ..  LIKE SO:

```
echo '<time style="width:194px;" datetime="' . date('H:i m-d-Y', $ts) . '" data-timezone="' . esc_attr($tz_param) . '">' . date('F j &\nb\sp;  &\nb\sp; <\s\p\a\n>H:i<\/\s\p\a\n>', $ts) . '</time>';
```

Comment: I am modifying my question. I didn't explain my question properly.

Comment: I have modified my question.